# Is It Immutable Class?

Tags: java

Does this below class is immutable?

```
class Immutable {

  private int x;

  Immutable(int value) {
    this.x = value;
  }

  public int getX(){
    return x;
  }
}
```

1. Class is not final Since no member is visible to sub class
2. Instance Variable x is not final since there is no setter method.

Is there any possiblity this class will break the contract of Immutable functionality without adding any code in this class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joshua Bloch in his "Effective Java" states that *"you should either design your classes for extensibility or make them non-extensible"*.

If flexibility is your primary concern and you have a strong reason to design your immutable class for inheritance - leave this class non-final.

If security is your concern - make this class final and member field final. Because:

- Non-final classes can be extended to create a mutable child classes by overriding getter method.
- Java is [reflective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29) by design. As Belgther told it's possible to set the value of member field using reflection. (no matter private or public) A long time ago [I used this](http://gate.ac.uk/releases/gate-3.1-build2270-ALL/doc/java2html/debugger/ClassRipper.java.html) to integrate my specific debugger with another project.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This answer in bulletin is cleared my doupt throughly.

Answer (score 6):

The class is practically immutable.

But you can still use reflection to set the value of the variable x since the variable is not final.

Comment: I think even `final` variables are not safe from reflections. No Sources, sorry.

Comment: oooh Thanks beigther. This question is asked in my interview and I said completely fine.

Comment: @st0le IIRC, this is something which has changed between releases. There's a technique to set final variables by using reflection on the `Field` object to remove the apparent `final` modifier.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline, I thought so. JDK5 i think?

Answer (score 6):

The `Immutable` class is immutable.

However, it is possible to declare a subclass of `Immutable` whose instances are mutable.  Indeed, the only way to prevent this is to make this class `final` ... or make its constructor private.

You could argue (and I would) that a mutable subclass of `Immutable` is violating the contract of `Immutable`.

---

The approach of changing the value of `x` using reflection is breaking the rules.  The Java specs say that the behavior of an application that does this is unspecified.  (Certainly, it breaks all sorts of assumptions that the JLS says that the JIT compiler is allowed to make.)

A sensible developer won't do that kind of thing, will discount the possibility of someone else doing it, and will say that `Immutable` is immutable despite the theoretical possibility that some total lunatic could change it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems to me that it's immutable.

Since you have a private field that can only be set in the constructor and the only method in that class is a getter, then that field cannot be modified anymore, and the class can be said immutable.